# How can I Change the Text and Link of a Windows Forms LinkLabel

Tags: c#, winforms, linklabel

I'd like to have only a link and the entire text clickable and both dynamically set. I don't know how to replace them. I tried below code and when it gets called more than one time I get `null pointer exception` error.

I tried using this:

```
void setLink(string label, string link)
{
    linkLabel1.Text = label;

    if (linkLabel1.Links.Count > 0)
    {
        linkLabel1.Links.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    linkLabel1.Links.Add(0, label.Length, link);
}
```

that's called from like this:

```
foreach(Foo f in fooArr) {
   setLink(f.name, f.url);
   // ... do something
}
```

`Foo` is:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string url { get; set;  }
}
```

and `fooArr` just `List<Foo>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `LinkLabel.Links` collection makes reference to a start position and length of the hyperlinked label string, I believe there is an issue if there is already more than one link in the `LinkLabel.Links` collection, which links to an existing `Text`. When you replace the text, and just the first link, it means that the existing links now reference parts of a string which are longer than the new string, and / or it may create overlapping links.

```
linkLabel1.Text = "A really long link and I'm linking the last bit";
linkLabel1.Links.Add(0, 5, "www.removeme.com");
var longLength = linkLabel1.Text.Length;
linkLabel1.Links.Add(longLength - 5, longLength - 1, "endofstring.com");
setLink("short", "newlink.com"); // What about endofstring.com?
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to replace the whole text and all links every time, so this is easily fixed with `Links.Clear()` to remove all links:

```
void setLink(string label, string link)
{
    linkLabel1.Text = label;
    linkLabel1.Links.Clear();
    linkLabel1.Links.Add(0, label.Length, link);
}
```

Comment: The `if` check isn't even needed and `Clear()` is much better than `RemoveAt()` (in that contexto). Thanks!

Comment: FWIW: The LinkLabel implementation does prevent overlapping links, but the logic used might not be what you want or expect.